# Get datetime object

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

Hi all i want a datetime object. In which I want to set time part by my own.

Like i want DateTime object who will have todays system date and I want to set its time to 08:00:00.

Comment: The number of people every day that can't find the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) for the `DateTime` structure built into their language is more than worrisome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

[DateTime structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: DateTime meetingAppt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,08, 00, 0);

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18);
```

Will give you a date value of The current date, at 6pm.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 8, 0, 0);`

That is the simplest I guess, in another case you can also create an extension method on DateTime probably to return you the above!

An extension method will also enable you to call it something like `DateTime.MyToday()` which will return you the current date with time set to 8:00:00 by default. So you need not do the entire `new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 8, 0, 0);`  every time you need this kind of date.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime meetingAppt = new DateTime(
    DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 8, 0, 0);
```